# Regex excluding catches that ending with a dot

Tags: regex

**First of all, I don't need full e-mail address validation**, my given task doesn't require it. I just want to upgrade my current regex code so that it won't match addresses ending with a dot.

My current code: `[0-9A-Za-z.]+[@][0-9A-Za-z.]+`

**It catches both** "`user@exampe.com`", "`user@example.com`."

I'd like it to catch **only from the string that ends without the dot**. `user@exampe.com`

**Example string:**

`dasd.fas@fsaf.dfas.dsa`, `zghs@gas.gsq`, `adg32.dsa12@cas`, *ksak@c.csa.*, *gs32.basaa@scaa.upc.*

I'd like to catch the strings marked as code in the example.

**Edit:** I have only one line with multiple e-mail addresses separated with a `,` and a `space` after them.

Comment: End with `[^.]$`?

Comment: Try `^YOUR-RE\b$`

Comment: @ssieightynine, what is the character/sring between each email strings? tell us what is the whole input string is exactly.

Comment: Please specify a language or tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might add `[0-9A-Za-z]`after your regex to end with what you want to match in your character class without the dot followed by a positive lookahead `(?=, |$)` that asserts what follows is either a comma followed by a whitespace or the end of the string.

`[0-9A-Za-z.]+@[0-9A-Za-z.]+[0-9A-Za-z](?=, |$)`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/27R3Uw/1)

Answer (score 1):

`([0-9A-z.]+@(?:\.?[0-9A-z]+)+)(?=,|$)`

#### [Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/ruL0cB/7)

Comment: Doesn't work if the last string doesn't end in a `.`

Comment: Fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

just capture `,` , `$` and group them in non-capturing group except end `.`

```
[0-9A-Za-z.]+[@][0-9A-Za-z.]+[0-9A-Za-z](?:(,|$))
```

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/w1Xm9E/3)

Comment: @sasieightynine upated try it now

Answer (score 0):

Just slightly modify your pattern: `[0-9A-Za-z.]+[@](?:[a-zA-Z]|\.(?=[a-zA-Z]))+`.

It uses alternation after `@` to match one or more: letters OR dot, if it's followed by another letter, thanks to positive lookahead: `\.(?=[a-zA-Z])`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2SA5y2/1)